# I cannot navigate between carousel my slides

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, carousel

I have been working on a carousel for my website. everything looks correct when I open the page (picture shows up, dots are in place, and the next and prev buttons show up). but when I try to click on next or previous it doesn't do anything. been trying to fix it for awhile now but I just can't figure out what is wrong. Any help would be great.

My Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-sm-12">

            <div id = "my-slider" class = "carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <!--indicators dot nav -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="0" class = "active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                </ol>

                <!--Wrapper for slide -->
                <div class = "carousel-inner" role = "listbox">

                    <div class = "item active">
                        <img src = "image/img1.jpg" alt = "stuff"/>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>header</h1>
                            <p>and paragraph</>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "item">
                        <img src = "image/img2.jpg" alt = "stupid stuff"/>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>header</h1>
                            <p>and paragraph</>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "item">
                        <img src = "image/img3.jpg" alt = "other stuff"/>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>header</h1>
                            <p>and paragraph</>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "item">
                        <img src = "image/img4.jpg" alt = "more stuff"/>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>header</h1>
                            <p>and paragraph</>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "item">
                        <img src = "image/img5.jpg" alt = "last stuff"/>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>header</h1>
                            <p>and paragraph</>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role = "button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden ="true"></span>
                    <span class = "sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role = "button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden = "true"></span>
                    <span class = "sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>

            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This question is borderline not descriptive enough. Always try to show an example of what you have tried rather then just throwing all of your code and problem out there. It shows you have tried to diagnose a specific problem rather than asking the community to write code for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+carrousel

Comment: do you receive any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?? This is why frameworks exist. Whenever you are trying to apply a component just look for a framework. It will save a lot of time for you. I recommend using this one: [jQuery thumbnail scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-thumbnail-scroller/)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the example code from the Bootstrap slider. If so, you need to make sure the bootstrap.js is linked as well as jQuery for the slider to work.